# Converting jQuery to no conflict mode

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's a script I'm using.

```
$(window).load(function() {
$('#edifici, #artistici, #industriale, #fotovoltaico, #veterinaria, #architettonici').hide();

if (!!window.location.hash) {
    var hash = window.location.hash;
    var $content = $(hash);
    showContent($content)
}

$('.home').click(function () {
    var id = this.id.replace('mostra_', '');
    var $content = $('#' + id + ':not(:visible)');
    if ($('.current').length === 0) {
        showContent($content)
    } else {
        $('.current').fadeOut(600, function () {
            showContent($content)
        });
    }
});

function showContent(content) {
    content.fadeIn(600);
    $('.current').removeClass('current');
    content.addClass('current');
}
});
```

As per [this guide](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/), to use it in WordPress (which has jQuery in no-conflict mode) I modified my script to

```
jQuery.noConflict();

jQuery(window).load(function($) {
$('#edifici, #artistici, #industriale, #fotovoltaico, #veterinaria, #architettonici').hide();

if (!!window.location.hash) {
    var hash = window.location.hash;
    var $content = $(hash);
    showContent($content)
}

$('.home').click(function () {
    var id = this.id.replace('mostra_', '');
    var $content = $('#' + id + ':not(:visible)');
    if ($('.current').length === 0) {
        showContent($content)
    } else {
        $('.current').fadeOut(600, function () {
            showContent($content)
        });
    }
});

function showContent(content) {
    content.fadeIn(600);
    $('.current').removeClass('current');
    content.addClass('current');
}
});
```

Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work properly... what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried replacing all the `$` with `jQuery` ?

Comment: `.load` doesn't pass a reference to jQuery to the callback: http://api.jquery.com/load-event/. Only `.ready` does.

Comment: The [`.load()` method](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) isn't called with `jQuery` as an argument, it is called with the `event` object as an argument. You're mixing it up with the [`.ready()` method](http://api.jquery.com/ready/).

Answer (score 6):

```
jQuery.noConflict();
```

> **Description: Relinquish jQuery's control of the $ variable**.

This means jQuery will not use $ anymore, so it will clear all conflicts with other libraries.

To use $ internally you can do the following:

You can wrap the existing code into an anonymous function and pass jQuery as an argument, for example:

```
(function ($) {

    // use $ here
    $('#hello').html('world');

})(jQuery);
```

or use a shortcut offered by jQuery:

```
jQuery(function($) {

    // use $
    $('#hello').html('world');

});
```

ready method also passes the jQuery object:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    // ...
});
```