# Loading in jQuery No Conflict Mode in WordPress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to get rid of this Uncaught TypeError:

> $ is not a function at javascript.js?ver=5.0.3:65

This is a WordPress theme, and I thought I had properly loaded scripts in the `functions.php` file:

```
wp_enqueue_script('script-name', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/js/javascript.js', array('jquery'), false, true);
```

Then as is suggested in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18681932/converting-jquery-to-no-conflict-mode), I wrapped the existing code into an anonymous function and passed jQuery as an argument

```
(function($){
  // code
})(jQuery);
```

Yet the TypeError remains. I would like to load jQuery in noConflict mode but don't understand how else to do it besides adding `jQuery.noConflict();` to the top of my `javascript.js` file. I tried this and it did not work.

Any suggestions are appreciated for how to do this correctly.

My site is live here: https://refresh.drawyourpets.com/

Comment: Have you loaded jQuery *before* that JS file?

Comment: I don't think so. Where would I do that - in `header.php`?

Comment: I think WordPress would load it automatically, since it's listed as a dependency for the enqueued script.

Comment: @Aioros right, it should be loaded. So then why the TypeError? I've read this article about wrapping the code in an IIFE https://digwp.com/2011/09/using-instead-of-jquery-in-wordpress/ But I've done this also, so....?

Answer (score 1):

So I went and looked at your script, and it looks a bit like this:

```
(function($){
    // uses $
})

(function($){
    // uses $
})

(jQuery);
```

This seems quite wrong to me, even from a purely syntactic point of view. What you want to do is wrap your script once, like this:

```
(function($) {
    // your entire script using $ normally:
})(jQuery);
```

The idea is that you are passing `jQuery` to a function that's immediately executed, and inside the function you can call it `$` safely.